How to Fix Zero Risk of Loss in Bootstrapping Profit Calculation: Machine Learning
I have just finished a project for my bootcamp. However, no matter how I do the profit calculation or bootstrapping, I continue to get a risk of loss of zero. I'm not sure how to fix this.
\### Key Values for Profit Calculation

BUDGET = 100 \* 10\*\*6  # $100 million

REVENUE_PER_BARREL = 4.5  # $4.5 per barrel

WELLS_SELECTED = 200  # Number of wells selected for development

COST_PER_WELL = BUDGET / WELLS_SELECTED  # Cost per well

sufficient_volume = COST_PER_WELL / REVENUE_PER_BARREL

### Profit Calculation Function
def calculate_profit(predictions, target, n_wells, revenue_per_barrel, cost_per_well):
    selected_indices = predictions.sort_values(ascending=False).head(n_wells).index
    selected_reserves = target.loc[selected_indices].sum()
    revenue = selected_reserves * revenue_per_barrel * 1000
    profit = revenue - (cost_per_well * n_wells)
    return profit

### Bootstrapping Technique
def bootstrap_profit(predictions, target, n_wells, revenue_per_barrel, cost_per_well, n_samples=1000):
    state = np.random.RandomState(42)
    profits = []
    for _ in range(n_samples):
        sample_indices = state.choice(predictions.index, size=n_wells, replace=True)
        sample_predictions = predictions.loc[sample_indices]
        sample_target = target.loc[sample_indices]
        profit = calculate_profit(sample_predictions, sample_target, n_wells, revenue_per_barrel, cost_per_well)
        profits.append(profit)
    profits = pd.Series(profits)
    mean_profit = profits.mean()
    lower_bound = profits.quantile(0.025)
    upper_bound = profits.quantile(0.975)
    risk_of_loss = (profits < 0).mean() * 100
    return mean_profit, (lower_bound, upper_bound), risk_of_loss

